# STM32 Discovery board + code readout protection

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32ldiscovery

Is it possible to enable readout protection on STM32 discovery board?
First I've tried STM32F429I-DISC1 but after enabling RDP with "stm32f4x lock 0" command (I'm using Linux/OpenOCD) MCU doesn't seem to work until sending unlock command (and writing new firmware).
Then I found following statement in this board documentation: 'Known limitation:
• Activating the readout protection on the ST-LINK/V2-B target, prevents the target application from running afterwards. The target readout protection must be kept disabled on the ST-LINK/V2-B boards.'

After that I've tried TM32L100CDISCOVERY - its documentation doesn't have such limitation note, and also its ST-LINK/V2 board, not ST-LINK/V2-B. But I've got exactly same behaviour - everything works fine - LEDs blinking as I programmed, but after locking (with 'stm32lx lock 0' command and subseqyent power cycle) - target MCU doesn't do anything.

So, it looks like no one discovery board support RDP protection at all and if I want to play with this feature - I anyway need to make a custom device? Or its possible with stock demo board but I did something wrong?

The full commands sequence to lock looks so:

```
init 
reset halt
stm32lx lock 0
reset halt
exit
```

.. or stm32F4x instead of stm32lx for STM32F429I board

Comment: I assume since all you have to do is change boot0 to go into the bootloader you can read whatever flash you want, there is no read out protection.  But I could be wrong you are way deeper into the docs than I am.  Good luck making your own microcontroller...If boot0 is the only weakness then you could remove and grind that pin off.

Comment: What did ST say when you asked them?

Comment: Eventually I managed to enable RDP on STM32L100 discovery board. Somewhy second "reset halt" causes problems. So this works:
init
reset halt
stm32lx lock 0
exit
..and power cycle of course. But only STM32L100, STM32F429I discovery board still doesn't work, but at least for it this documented.